# SQLAlchemy: proper way to specify connection URL in python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy (version **2.0.4**)to connect to a remote MySQL server from python via the pymysql driver.

If I declare my connection URL in the "simple" way, it works:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
engine = db.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://dbuser:verysecret@myhost.com:9001/mydb")
```

but I'd prefer this other version I've found in a tutorial:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
connect_url = db.engine.url.URL(
    "mysql+pymysql",
    username="dbuser",
    password="verysecret",
    host="myhost.com",
    port="9001",
    database="mydb",
)

engine = db.create_engine(connect_url)
```

but this fails on the connect_url line as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bob/Documents/work/code/mysqltest/mysqltest/sqlalch.py", line 3, in <module>
    connect_url = db.engine.url.URL(
TypeError: URL.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

EDIT: thanks to @snakecharmer's reply below I then tried to add a valid query parameter as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

connect_url = db.engine.url.URL(
    "mysql+pymysql",
    username="root",
    password="ghj12WQ_AA1997",
    host="isagog.com",
    port=9001,
    database="athena",
    query=dict(charset="utf8mb4"),
)

engine = db.create_engine(connect_url)
```

And this does works well. But still not sure why I get an error if the query parameter is not provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to pass any query parameters, pass an empty string or dict for query:

```
>>> url = sa.engine.URL('mysql+pymysql', 'root', 'root', 'localhost', 3306, 'test', {})
>>> url
mysql+pymysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test
```

If you need to pass query arguments, pass them as a dictionary:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>>
>>> url = sa.engine.URL('mysql+pymysql', 'root', 'root', 'localhost', 3306, 'test', {'charset': 'utf8mb4'})
>>> url
mysql+pymysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test?charset=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Thank you very much but that is not what I'm trying to ask. As you can see from my first snippet, the URL as a string without query does work without problems. It's the second form I'm trying to use and that complains about this query missing.

Comment: I'm using the second form, am I not?  What version of SQLAlchemy are you using, and what error do you get if you pass a `query` argument?  Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Ops yes you are, sorry misread. Adding back the 2.0.4 version that was edited out. Adding details to question. Thanks a lot.